# Plot columns from a dataframe by choosing rows at an interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 10,000 rows and want to plot two columns from the dataframe by choosing rows at an interval of 50 i.e. plot a new data frame which has rows 0,50,100...

This is how my dataframe looks like(shortened the size for readability):

```py
energy_list=[['Step', 'Temp', 'E_pair', 'E_mol', 'TotEng', 'Press'],
 ['0', '0', '-30039.2', '0', '-30039.2', '719.23759'],
 ['1', '8.1409265', '-30039.407', '0', '-30039.206', '689.44014'],
 ['2', '28.416286', '-30039.924', '0', '-30039.222', '605.33679'],
 ['3', '50.908637', '-30040.492', '0', '-30039.235', '480.95995'],
 ['4', '65.547515', '-30040.856', '0', '-30039.238', '334.70744'],
 ['5', '66.963076', '-30040.88', '0', '-30039.227', '184.70683'],
 ['6', '56.169577', '-30040.594', '0', '-30039.207', '45.648253'],
 ['7', '39.132486', '-30040.152', '0', '-30039.186', '-72.297212'],
 ['8', '23.621873', '-30039.753', '0', '-30039.17', '-162.75599'],
 ['9', '15.932485', '-30039.555', '0', '-30039.161', '-221.52774'],
 ['10', '18.71954', '-30039.622', '0', '-30039.16', '-245.17833'],
 ['11', '30.549774', '-30039.915', '0', '-30039.161', '-230.6655'],
 ['12', '46.928744', '-30040.318', '0', '-30039.16', '-176.15559']]

import pandas as pd
header=energy_list.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(energy_list, columns=header)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['Step'], df['TotEng']) # This is where I want to choose rows at intervals of 50 instead of plotting all the rows in the dataframe
plt.show()
```

I don't mind creating a new dataframe with rows at an interval of 50 but would wanna know the most efficient(memory and speed) way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy notation should be as quick as simple to use, without waste of memory:

```
plt.scatter(df['Step'][0::50], df['TotEng'][0::50])
```

Answer (score -1):

It is simpler to mask the data frame to separate the data from the visualization.

```
mask = np.arange(0, len(df), 50)
df = df.iloc[df['Step'].iloc[mask]]
```

Comment: That is not a mask, it is equivalent to access the data by index. A mask is a boolean series and you can do it like following: 
```mask = np.empty(len(df.index), dtype=bool)
mask[0::50] = True
plot_df = df.iloc[mask]```